# Is it possible to get all triggers associated with a table using sql server 2008 clr programming?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Is it possible to use .net (C# SQL CLR) to find all the triggers associated with a table?

And also will I be able to determine the type of that trigger? - CLR or T-SQL?

Thanks,
Chaks

Answer (score 1):

Well we've got the [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) including [Database.Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.triggers.aspx), or you can always consume some T-SQL commands from within .NET and look at some of the system views such as [sys.triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188746.aspx) if you have permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a query againts the system tables. Something like the following:

```
SELECT  tr.name as TriggerName,
        tr.type_desc TriggerType,
        tbl.name TableName,
        sch.table_schema SchemaName
FROM    sys.objects tr
INNER JOIN sys.objects tbl
    ON (tr.parent_object_id = tbl.object_id
        AND tbl.name = 'SomeTableName')
INNER JOIN information_schema.tables sch
    ON (tbl.name = sch.table_name)
WHERE tr.type IN ('TR', 'TA')
```

**NOTE:** type_desc values are **CLR_TRIGGER** and **SQL_TRIGGER** respectively.